While get user’s list of followed sites By calling GET /me/followedSites endpoint gives "access denied”
followedSites = await graphClient.Me.FollowedSites.Request().GetAsync();

I am using this, and it is not able to get followedsites data and gives 404

StatusCode: Forbidden RawResponseBody:
{"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"Access
denied","innerError":{"date":"2024-05-06T05:03:33","request-id":"85c976e5-6309-462e-a2d5-89ab8c90d24b","client-request-id":"85c976e5-6309-462e-a2d5-89ab8c90d24b"}}}

Please let me know if there is any other enpoint that I can try with.
I checked required permisson as delegated for sites.read.all and sites.read
still it fails.

I think you might need more permissions under Microsoft Graph.

Can you please specify a required permission to be granted to access the sharepoint sites.
